Could someone help me understand this proof from the book Putnam and Beyond
Let $F = \{E_1,E_2, . . . , E_s\}$ be a family of subsets with $r$ elements of some
set $X$. Show that if the intersection of any $r + 1$ (not necessarily distinct) sets in $F$ is
nonempty, then the intersection of all sets in $F$ in nonempty.
Solution. Again we assume the contrary, namely that the intersection of all sets in $F$ is
empty. Consider the set $E_1 = \{x_1, x_2, . . . , x_r \}$. Because none of the $x_i$ , $i = 1, 2, . . . , r$,
lies in the intersection of all the $E_j$ ’s (this intersection being empty), it follows that for
each $i$ we can find some $E_{j_i}$ such that $x_i  \notin E_{j_i}$ .
Then
$$E_1 ∩ E_{i_1}
∩ E_{i_2}
∩ · · · ∩ E_{i_r}
= ∅$$,
since, at the same time, this intersection is included in $E_1$ and does not contain any
element of $E_1$. But this contradicts the hypothesis. It follows that our initial assumption
was false, and hence the sets from the family $F$ have a nonempty intersection.
I don't understand the $E_{j_i}$ part is that one of the $E_1, ..., E_s$ and how is the above intersection included in $E_1$

If I am understanding your English at the very end, you're confused on the choice of how the intersection is constructed, and why the intersection is included in $E_{1}$.
To answer the first, I should note that, if that is the notation chosen by the book (I don't have it), it is a pretty terrible choice to swap aroundthe indices names $i, j$ like that from $E_{j_{i}}$ to $E_{i_{1}} \cap \cdots$. The point is that, given the $r$ elements of $E_{1}$, denoted $x_{j}$, you find some set $E_{i_{j}}$ that doesn't include that element. Now take the intersection of all the $j$ sets you found with your original set $E_{1}$:
$$E_{1} \cap E_{i_{1}} \cap E_{i_{2}} \cap \cdots \cap E_{i_{r}}$$
Now, because of how the sets $E_{i_{j}}$ were chosen, if you use the set-theoretic definition of intersections of sets:
$$A \cap B = \{ x \in A \cup B \, : \, x \in A \text{ and } x \in B \}$$
(this might be technically wrong, but it gets the point across) the intersection given needs to contain all the elements of $E_{1}$. However, because we designed all the other sets to not SIMULTANEOUSLY possess any of the elements of $E_{1}$, the intersection is empty.
As for why the intersection is included in $E_{1}$, I recommend taking the intersection of two sets and drawing a Venn diagram, and observing where the intersection lies.
P.S. given the comment by OP: For the last step, we now see an intersection of $r + 1$ sets is empty, while the initial hypothesis is that the intersection of any $r + 1$ sets would be nonempty.
Truth be told though, this is less a proof by contradiction and more a proof of contrapositive, if I am reading it right.

sorry but I think I don't understand the last step "since, at the same time, this intersection is included in $_1$ and does not contain any element of $_1$. But this contradicts the hypothesis." I don't understand how the hypothesis is contradicted, but I understand why $A \cap B$ is contained within $A$

If there was an $x$ such that you couldn't find some $E_{j}$ such that $x \notin E_{j}$, then $x$ would be in all the $E_{i}$ and the the intersection would be non-empty.
$E_1 ∩ E_{i_1}
∩ E_{i_2}
∩ · · · ∩ E_{i_r}
= ∅$
The above construction is based on the fact that we are attaching the exact set that corresponds to the relevant $x_{i}$ via the fact that $x_i  \notin E_{j_i}$.
As for why the intersection is "included" in $E_{1}$, it appears that is because
$E_1 ∩ E_{i_1}
∩ E_{i_2}
∩ · · · ∩ E_{i_r}\subseteq E_{1}$
Consider each $x_{i}\in E_{1}$ and it wont be an element of the intersection since it corresponds to the set $E_{i_j}$ for some $j$, so then no element of $E_{1}$ is in the intersection $E_1 ∩ E_{i_1}
∩ E_{i_2}
∩ · · · ∩ E_{i_r}$ which means the intersection is empty.
This contradicts the hypothesis because the argumentation consisted of using the contrapositive: The intersection construction shows that there is an empty intersection of $r+1$ sets of the family of subsets $F$.
